# jQuery - setTimeout not working with $(this).find

Tags: jquery, settimeout, mouseleave

What I am trying to do obviously is target a specific "gridWrap" element (the one being hovered over) and remove a class after 500ms but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I have

```
$(".gridWrap").mouseleave(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).find('.gridOverlay').removeClass('active');
  }, 500);
  $(this).find('.viewSite').removeClass('bounceInDown').addClass('bounceOutUp');
});
```

This works just fine but i need to delay the "active" class removal:

```
$(".gridWrap").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).find('.gridOverlay').removeClass('active');
$(this).find('.viewSite').removeClass('bounceInDown').addClass('bounceOutUp');
});
```

Comment: within the callback `this` context refers to something else

Comment: `setTimeout((function(){
    $(this).find('.gridOverlay').removeClass('active');
  }).bind(this), 500);`

Comment: `setTimeout(()=>{
    $(this).find('.gridOverlay').removeClass('active');
  }, 500);`

Comment: `let $this = $(this); setTimeout(function(){
    $this.find('.gridOverlay').removeClass('active');
  }, 500);`

Comment: probably it would be a duplicate mate :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the this context changes in timeout function.
Try this one:

```
$(".gridWrap").mouseleave(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    self.find('.gridOverlay').removeClass('active');
  }, 500);
  $(this).find('.viewSite').removeClass('bounceInDown').addClass('bounceOutUp');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable for this before 'settimeout' it work well